# How did my UITableView instantiate its own cells?

Tags: uitableview

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is instantiating a nib??

[image: Stack Trace]

I ask because it seems to be instantiating more cells than it could show on the screen at one time.  (though *fewer* than the total number of rows in the table)

I'm using a [FRCTableViewDataSource](https://github.com/freerangecode/FRCTableViewDataSources) to bind my table view to some Artist objects in Core Data.  I don't think that matters though, it's just acting as the data source for a vanilla table view.

Here's their implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath (I added the log statements)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = nil;
    Class theCellClass = [self cellClassAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([theCellClass isSubclassOfClass:[FRCTableViewCell class]])
        cellIdentifier = [theCellClass reuseIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%@", cellIdentifier);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell);

    ...

    return cell;
}
```

And here's my implementation of awakeFromNib

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"waking");
}
```

The console output looks like this:

```
ArtistTableViewCell
waking
<ArtistTableViewCell: 0xc678ad0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 295 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc6789f0>>
```

TL;DR my table view has more initiative than your table view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the reuse identifier properly in the cell's nib?
If not, you'll get a new cell everytime, since the reuse ids won't match.

Otherwise, yeah, this version of dequeue will instantiate a nib if nothing can be dequeued.
From there, it'll create your cell instance, call awake from nib, yadyadayada.

Comment: I'm used to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returning nil the first time it's called.  How does it know which nib to instantiate?

Comment: Apple made the usual dequeue, if nil load nib pattern easier starting iOS5. You can register a nib for a reuse identifier, in which case dequeuing will load the nib for you if nothing can be dequeued.